# Magento 2: Cart price rule condition programmatically

Tags: magento2, cart, rules, programatically

I have a cart price rule whose id is 5. This rule applied for all customers and no condition applied to this. I want to make a condition on this rule is **False** when the payment method is **paypal_billing_agreement**  You can see in the screenshot

[image]

This condition I make from the admin panel But my requirement changes, now I want to do this by InstallData.php or other way But should be programmatically in my custom module. Because my some other functionality related to these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the best practices in Magento 2 you need to use Repositories to create/save entities. However, there are still some issues with repositories for particular entities, including the SalesRule and that's why I will describe here how to achieve it directly via model (the same way how it's implemented in Magento 2 core).

In your class constructor inject the Rule Factory

```
protected $ruleFactory

public function __construct(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory) {
    $this->rulesFactory = $ruleFactory
}
```

After this, inside of the method, where you are going to create the rule, init the rule data, assign the date to the rule model and save the model:

```
$ruleData = [
            "name" => "Buy 3 tee shirts and get the 4th free",
            "description" => "Buy 3 tee shirts and get the 4th free",
            "from_date" => null,
            "to_date" => null,
            "uses_per_customer" => "0",
            "is_active" => "1",
            "stop_rules_processing" => "0",
            "is_advanced" => "1",
            "product_ids" => null,
            "sort_order" => "0",
            "simple_action" => "buy_x_get_y",
            "discount_amount" => "1.0000",
            "discount_qty" => null,
            "discount_step" => "3",
            "apply_to_shipping" => "0",
            "times_used" => "0",
            "is_rss" => "1",
            "coupon_type" => "NO_COUPON",
            "use_auto_generation" => "0",
            "uses_per_coupon" => "0",
            "simple_free_shipping" => "0",
            "customer_group_ids" => [0, 1, 2, 3],
            "website_ids" => [1],
            "coupon_code" => null,
            "store_labels" => [],
            "conditions_serialized" => '',
            "actions_serialized" => ''
        ];

$ruleModel = $this->ruleFactory->create();
$ruleModel->setData($ruleData);
$ruleModel->save();
```

All conditions and actions can be assigned via conditions_serialized and actions_serialized fields. They are empty in this example since they have large values usually. To get the corresponding serialized values for your rule go to admin panel, create a rule with all values you want, save it and check the POST parameters of the save request. You will be able to extract the serialized values from the POST request.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: I have to not create new cart rule. I have to just update condition of cart rule id 5 and where you define conditions in the above code?

Comment: updated my answer pls check